# dynamically change consumers - rabbitMQ

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am trying to dynamically change consumers.but at one point no.of consumers are going beyond the max - consumers.
the code is:

```
public class RabbitMQConfig extends AMQPConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry endpoint; 
    static int temp=0;   
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory  factory;

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(final RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar){
    registrar.setContainerFactory(rabbitListenerContainerFactory());
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
}

public AmqpTemplate getAmqpTemplate() {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter ((MessageConverter)consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() 
{

    factory=new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(15);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(10);
    return factory;
}

public void  throttleConsumers(){

    Collection<MessageListenerContainer> containers= endpoint.getListenerContainers();
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer  eachSimpleMessageListenerContainer=null;
    for(MessageListenerContainer eachContainer : containers)
    {
    if(eachContainer.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer")){
    eachSimpleMessageListenerContainer =(SimpleMessageListenerContainer)eachContainer;
    eachSimpleMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(12);
    }               
    }       
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(this.connectionFactory);
    }
```

}

The consumer is :

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
String queueName;   

static long messageCount=0L;

@Autowired
RabbitMQConfig config;

    @RabbitListener(queues="rabbitmq.queue")
    public void receivedMessage(String message) throws IOException {

    messageCount++;
    System.out.println(message);

    if(messageCount>10000 && messageCount<15000 )
    {
            System.out.println("consumed: "+messageCount);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("error sleeping:"+e.getMessage());
            }

    config.throttleConsumers();
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName,message);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/rabbitmq-consumer/throttle", String.class);
      System.out.println(quote);

    }


}
```

}

presently my min consumers are 15 and max are 20 and I am throttling to 12 once the response time of another program is greater than 800. while we are testing number of consumers are going upto 29 which we are unable understand.

Kindly help us to understand where we are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks gary for your response. it is rabbit mq 3.6.0 Erlang 20.0 . we will use DirectMessageListenerContainer. But, still wants to know the reason which we are unable to arrive at

Comment: I mean which version if Spring AMQP? There have been bug fixes in the past.

Comment: using 1.5.12.RELEASE for spring-boot-starter-amqp

Comment: Forget my comment about `DirectMessageListenerContainers`; it doesn't support changing consumer counts. I have issued a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/745) to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it with similar code and saw no problems if I change the min before I reached the max...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50014436Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50014436Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template, AmqpAdmin admin,
            RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                template.convertAndSend("so50014436", "foo");
            }
            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            exec.execute(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(admin.getQueueProperties("so50014436"));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5_000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(30_000);
            System.out.println("Changing min to 12");
            registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(c -> {
                ((SimpleMessageListenerContainer) c).setConcurrentConsumers(12);
            });
            Thread.sleep(60_000);
            exec.shutdownNow();
        };
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so50014436")
    public void listen(String in) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1_000);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so50014436");
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=10
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.max-concurrency=15
```

and

```
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=10, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=832, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=10, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=978, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=10, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=933, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=11, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=883, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=11, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=830, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=12, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=774, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
Changing min to 12
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=14, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=712, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=14, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=642, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=570, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=495, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=420, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=345, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=270, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=195, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=120, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=45, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
```

However, if I wait until we've reached the max, I do see a problem...

```
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=10, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=695, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=10, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=940, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=10, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=890, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=11, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=847, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=11, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=792, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=12, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=736, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=12, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=676, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=12, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=616, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=13, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=552, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=13, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=487, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=14, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=420, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=14, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=350, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=14, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=280, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=15, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=205, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
Changing min to 12
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=17, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=128, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=17, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=43, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=17, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=17, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
{QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT=16, QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT=0, QUEUE_NAME=so50014436}
```

...where we go above the max. It's not clear why you got 29, though.

I have openened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-810) for this.

That said, it's not clear why you are changing the min to 12 when you are already at the max (15).

Comment: Thanks Gary for your effort. we want to decrease number of messages to be consumed at one point so for that we thought decreasing number of consumers will do.

Comment: Even with [this fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/745), reducing the `concurrentConsumers` when there is a `maxConcurrentConsumers` won't have any effect, since that allows more consumers. Even without the fix, not setting the `maxConcurrentConsumers` will allow you to increase/reduce the consumer count. The bug was when you did that **and** there is a max.